# List groupe inside dialog renders title out of correct position

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

List group component renders data incorrectly-
the title that should be on the slot activator tile is being rendered along with the drop-down elements.

I used an example of vuetify.js API here:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists.
even with the original example, i get the same results.

Outer component:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
      <v-dialog :v-model="dialog" persistent width="800">
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title class="headline grey lighten-4" primary-title>File Results
                <v-spacer/>
                <v-btn flat icon @click="close">
                  <v-icon color="black" medium>cancel</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-title>     
                <ResultListView/>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="primary" flat @click="openFileDialog">results</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

List component out of vuetify exapmle:

```
<template>
  <v-layout row>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
      <v-card>
        <v-toolbar color="teal" dark>
          <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>

          <v-toolbar-title>Topics</v-toolbar-title>

          <v-spacer></v-spacer>

          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>more_vert</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-toolbar>

        <v-list>
          <v-list-group
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.title"
            v-model="item.active"
            :prepend-icon="item.action"
            aria-expanded="true"
            no-action
          >
            <template v-slot:activator>
              <v-list-tile>
                <v-list-tile-content>
                  <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
                </v-list-tile-content>
              </v-list-tile>
            </template>

            <v-list-tile
              v-for="subItem in item.items"
              :key="subItem.title"
            >
              <v-list-tile-content>
                <v-list-tile-title>{{ subItem.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
              </v-list-tile-content>

              <v-list-tile-action>
                <v-icon>{{ subItem.action }}</v-icon>
              </v-list-tile-action>
            </v-list-tile>
          </v-list-group>
        </v-list>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        items: [
          {
            action: 'local_activity',
            title: 'Attractions',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'restaurant',
            title: 'Dining',
            active: true,
            items: [
              { title: 'Breakfast & brunch' },
              { title: 'New American' },
              { title: 'Sushi' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'school',
            title: 'Education',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'directions_run',
            title: 'Family',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'healing',
            title: 'Health',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'content_cut',
            title: 'Office',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'local_offer',
            title: 'Promotions',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I expect the results to be similar to the supplied API example
but I get the following result:

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: What version of vuetify are you using in your app?

Comment: the version is: 1.4.1

Comment: Ok, I'd thought if it was an old version it may be the cause but I don't think so. I can't replicate the issue you're having so can only think you have something else causing a clash but don't know. Try and test the list component on it's own, not in a dialog and add things in until it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use version 1.4.1, you should also look at the correct version's documentation of vuetify,
If you want to do any changes just go through this documentation for `v1` https://v1.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists#list, Or else just update vuetify version.
the below is the code for your solution,

```
<template>
  <v-layout row>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
      <v-card>
        <v-toolbar color="teal" dark>
          <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
          <v-toolbar-title>Topics</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>more_vert</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-toolbar>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-group
            v-for="item in items"
            v-model="item.active"
            :key="item.title"
            :prepend-icon="item.action"
            no-action
          >
            <v-list-tile slot="activator">
              <v-list-tile-content>
                <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
              </v-list-tile-content>
            </v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile v-for="subItem in item.items" :key="subItem.title">
              <v-list-tile-content>
                <v-list-tile-title>{{ subItem.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
              </v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-action>
                <v-icon>{{ subItem.action }}</v-icon>
              </v-list-tile-action>
            </v-list-tile>
          </v-list-group>
        </v-list>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        items: [
          {
            action: 'local_activity',
            title: 'Attractions',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'restaurant',
            title: 'Dining',
            active: true,
            items: [
              { title: 'Breakfast & brunch' },
              { title: 'New American' },
              { title: 'Sushi' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'school',
            title: 'Education',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'directions_run',
            title: 'Family',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'healing',
            title: 'Health',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'content_cut',
            title: 'Office',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'local_offer',
            title: 'Promotions',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: @MichaelGabbay Cool,